# Insert a value in json file with python

Tags: python, json

For a project, I need to use json for store some values :

```
{
"Serial_011": "011",
"Servers_011":
    [
        {
            "hostname": "srv-a.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/1",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/2",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "hostname": "nsc-srv-b.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/3",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/4",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a service with this format :

`{
    "uri": "http://www.google.fr"
    "expected_code": 200
}`

So it will have this format :

```
{
"Serial_011": "011",
"Servers_011":
    [
        {
            "hostname": "srv-a.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/1",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/2",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr"
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "hostname": "nsc-srv-b.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/3",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/4",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can not do this... I try with .append() but it's in local, json.dumps() but i can not go further than the first indent...

This is what I try with .append() :

```
with open('Example_of_configuration', 'r') as f:
    dic = json.load(f)
    dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append('{"uri":"http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200}')
```

Somebody know how to do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mentioned that you tried with `.append()`, where is that code?

Comment: You need to deserialize the json into python objects and modify the data structure from there...

Comment: Ok thanks, but could you give me a tip for how doing this ?

Comment: Did you try `json.loads` instead ?

Comment: @mson what exactly do you want? For every object field `services` add that object? Or append the string "structure"???

Comment: I want add a service with the same structure than already in the json

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I will do a python script where I ask if the user want to add a service or not with an input() for example. After this I want to get this service and add it in the json just below existing service

Comment: json.dumps(dic) will give you a JSON string that you can write to a file

Comment: No, you need to be more specific about exactly what you want your final json to look like. How is the output of what you tried not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    dic = json.load(f)
    dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append({"uri": "http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200})

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dic, f)
```

Comment: Thanks it works. And if I want to add a server, I do the same thing but with dic['Servers_011'] ?

Comment: That's right but be sure that the new server is also a list of dictionaries (`[{
            "hostname": "srv-a.11", ...}, ...]`) and not a string

Comment: Just a little another question, if I want to remove one service, I need to use .remove() ? Because I have test something and it don't work :`dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].remove({"uri": "http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200})` and `with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(dic, f)`

Comment: @mson If you need to remove something, you can just use `del`. In order to remove the second service, use `del dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'][1]`

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a string value instead of the dictionary. Instead of:

```
dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append('{"uri":"http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200}')
```

Do

```
dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append({"uri":"http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200})  # as a dict with two keys, without quotes
```

Or like the old version:

```
dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append(structure)
```

(without quotes)

Using `dic` as an example:

```
>>> dic['Servers_011'][0]['services']  # before
[{'expected_code': 200, 'uri': 'http://www.google.fr/1'}, {'expected_code': 200, 'uri': 'http://www.google.fr/2'}]
>>> dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append({"uri":"http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200})
>>> dic['Servers_011'][0]['services']  # after
[{'expected_code': 200, 'uri': 'http://www.google.fr/1'}, {'expected_code': 200, 'uri': 'http://www.google.fr/2'}, {'expected_code': 200, 'uri': 'http://www.google.com'}]
>>>
```

And then you can (over)write it back to the same file, as per @julien-spronck's answer:

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dic, f)
```

Comment: Yeah but when the program ending, it will be not safe ?

Comment: No, after that you need to write it out with `json.dump()`

Comment: Ok I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct thing.But problem was like passing as a string.A small change is needed.Just remove the single quote while passing the structure.
Ultimately you want in the form of dict but you are passing as a string. That's obviously not possible.Please see the below to :

```
with open('Example_of_configuration', 'r') as f:
    dic = json.load(f)
    dic['Servers_011'][0]['services'].append({"uri":"http://www.google.com", "expected_code": 200})
```

I hope it will work.